# Can't find my registered details in the database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm a newbie to php and have been having issues on a project.I created a database and a table,created the register page and everything seems ok.however,all the details entered on the register page aren't appearing in the database.please can anyone help debug?the php code is as shown below

```
<?php 
session_start(); 

require_once('config.php'); 

?> 

<?php 
if (isset($_POST['register'])){ 
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$password = $_POST['password']; 
$cpassword = $_POST['confirm_password']; 

$sql = $con->query("INSERT into   'users' (id, name, email, 
password,confirm_password) VALUES     ('', {$name}', '{$email}', 
'{$password}', '{$cpassword}')"); 
die ("cannot connect to database;"); 
} 

?> 

CONFIG FILE: 
<?php 

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost",       "root", "","knux"); 

?>
```

Comment: `Wrap off quotes` form `table` name instead use `backtick`

Comment: What is your output? **var_dump**? did you do **error_reporting(E_ALL);**

Comment: Also missing `'` at `, {$name}',`

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing procedural and object oriented approaches. `mysqli_connect` returns handle, not object so you cannot use `$con->something`. Use this to create db connection:

`$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'knux');`

More: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Answer (score 0):

There is a single quote missing from your "n"

```
('', {$name}', '{$email}', '{$password}', '{$cpassword}')
```

It should be:

```
('', '{$name}', '{$email}', '{$password}', '{$cpassword}')
```

There might be issues from your html however, you can try these:

1. Make sure your fields are coming from the HTML from, you can do this with

   ```
   print_r($_POST);
   ```

   If you see all the input, then the fault is not from the HTML.
2. In this case, there's really no need for you to have two PHP tags in one file, instead of

   ```
   <?php 
    session_start(); 

    require_once('config.php'); 

   ?> 

   <?php 
    if (isset($_POST['register'])){ 
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    ...
   ?>
   ```

You can have:

```
   <?php 
     session_start(); 

     require_once('config.php'); 

     if (isset($_POST['register'])){ 
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     ...
    ?>
```

3. Use backticks when referring to the database elements like the table, instead of:

   ```
    INSERT into   'users' (id, name, email, password,confirm_password)
   ```

   do:

   ```
   INSERT into   `user` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `password`,`confirm_password`)
   ```
4. Use `mysql_error();` in your `or die();` so you'll have:

   ```
   or die(mysql_error());
   ```

This should tell you exactly what the issue is.

Since you're still learning however, ill recommend `PDO` instead of PHP's `mysql_` functions. If you're feeling too comfortable with it, you can use the `mysqli_` functions instead. `I` makes all the difference ;)

Comment: Print_r ($_POST) test as u suggested gave me the following output on my page: Array ([name]=>Steve [email]=>stv@gmail.com [password]=>123 [confirm_password]=>123 [register]=>)

Comment: @banky That means the problem of the html is solved, are you getting any errors when you submit?? There must be an output somehow when you submit, to see this better, you should implement my 4th suggestion. Also, remove the braces `{ }` from the values, let's see how that goes.

Answer (score -1):

There is 'n single quote missing `{$name}'`

Also if `id` is auto increment it can be removed from the `INSERT` statement

**Correct Way:**

```
$sql = $con->query("INSERT into   `users` (name, email, 
password,confirm_password) VALUES     ('{$name}', '{$email}', 
'{$password}', '{$cpassword}')");
```

Comment: Thanks buddie..I just corrected it still didn't work

Comment: What field type in the database table is id?